# Arrows on number line

Tags: arrows

How do I add arrows to both ends of this number line?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line=none,
  axis lines=left,
  axis line style={-},
  xmin=112.5,
  xmax=121.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  xlabel=$\mu$,
  scatter/classes={o={mark=*}},
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  xtick={113,114,...,121}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please post minimal working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is change the `axis line style`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis y line=none,
  axis lines=left,
  axis line style={<->},
  xmin=112.5,
  xmax=121.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  xlabel=$\mu$,
  scatter/classes={o={mark=*}},
  restrict y to domain=0:1,
  xtick={113,114,...,121}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As @azetina notes, you can also use `stealth`, by doing `axis line style={stealth-stealth},`, which might be more aesthetically appealing:

[image]

Comment: Using `stealth` looks much more appealing.